# Implement Spring Boot service for email

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to create Spring boot service which will be used into application:

Main Class with SNMTP server configuration:

```
public class MailConfiguration {

    public MailConfiguration() {
        // TODO add configuration for SNMP server
    }
}
```

Classes with specific body with each case:

```
public class NewUserNotifier extends MailConfiguration{

    public void sendNewUserNotifier() {
        // TODO Implement here logic
    }
}

public class TransactionLimitsNotifier extends MailConfiguration {

    public void sendTransactionLimitsNotifier() {
        // TODO Implement here logic
    }
}
```

How I can implement Spring service witch I can call using @Autowire when I can one main class with I need for configuration?

Comment: Refer to the article Spring Boot Freemarker Email Template http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-freemarker-email-template.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to extend the class that contains config for emails. You just create a method in it and annotate it with `@Bean`, then spring will inject its instance wherever it is called using `@Autowired`.

add this in dependency in pom.xml (if not already):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If using gradle, add this to build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
```

This is the configuration you need. You add this bean to a class that has `@Configuration` annotation:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
mailSender.setPort(587);

mailSender.setUsername("my.gmail@gmail.com");
mailSender.setPassword("password");     
Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");     
return mailSender;
}
```

Then to send emails, you would inject `JavaMailSender` in a class that is annotated with `@Component` (`@Service`, `@Controller`, and `@Repository` all are components) and start sending emails:

```
@Autowired
public JavaMailSender emailSender;

public void sendSimpleMessage(
  String to, String subject, String text) {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
    message.setTo(to); 
    message.setSubject(subject); 
    message.setText(text);
    emailSender.send(message);
}
```